# Jquery onclick delete i++

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of items defined by del1, del2, del3 and so on.

How do I set my .click to be .del1 delete(1) and .del2 delete(2)?

```
<li>
    <a href="http://www." target="new">http://www.</a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="del1" src="images/page_white_delete.png" title="Delete">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://www." target="new">http://www.</a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="del2" src="images/page_white_delete.png" title="Delete">
    </a>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".del1").click(function(){
   favs.webdb.deleteTodo(1);
});
```

The old code was written like this:

```
    <li><a href="http://www.tes.com" target="new">http://www.tes.com</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="favs.webdb.deleteTodo(1);">
<img src="images/page_white_delete.png" title="Delete">
</a></li>
```

I also think I might have to do a jquery live click because the webdb doesn't load until the page finishes loading.

Comment: You want to delete the whole list item containing the anchors and img?

Comment: actually this code deletes the item from the local web db favs.webdb.deleteTodo(1) I just can't set it through jQuery.

Comment: It used to be written this way. <li><a href="http://www.tes.com" target="new">http://www.tes.com</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="favs.webdb.deleteTodo(1);"><img src="images/page_white_delete.png" title="Delete"></a></li>

Comment: @Blynn: Can you change your HTML around, or is it fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'd better set a special attribute like:

```
<img class="del" data-node-id="1" src="images/page_white_delete.png" title="Delete">
```

then:

```
 $('img.del').click(function(){ 
      favs.webdb.deleteTodo( $(this).data('node-id') ); 
 })
```

Comment: This worked thanks! $('.del').live('click', function() {
  favs.webdb.deleteTodo( $(this).data('node-id') ); 

});

Answer (score 6):

Use a generic class and a `data-*` attribute:

```
<img class="del" data-number="1" src="images/page_white_delete.png" title="Delete">
<img class="del" data-number="2" src="images/page_white_delete.png" title="Delete">


$(".del").click(function(){
    favs.webdb.deleteTodo($(this).data("number"));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can't modify the HTML, you can extract the number from the `class` name:

```
$('img[class^="del"]').click(function() {
  var class = $(this).attr('class');
  var number = parseInt(class.slice(3), 10);

  favs.webdb.deleteTodo(number);
});
```